# How to sum up the values iterated by the mapper

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am new to use mapper following IKAI source to learn.

Assume the mapper is iterating over a datastore entity(Say PowerHouse which is having currentConsumption fields which maintains the amount of current consumed for each house)

I need the mapper tool to traverse the complete entity and get the sum of it currentConsumption field.
According to IKAI Demo
I am able to traverse the each row of PowerHouseTable but Not sure how to sum up the currentConsumption.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a Reducer step to aggregate the currentConsumption.

Normally, it is easy, just try to implement a Reduce function with regards to the Map function that you already have in order to aggregate the results.

Try to look on the WordCount example, it has almost the same principle that you are looking for.
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v2.0

So, in the word count example, in the map function,  it gets word by word and assign to it 1. That means, the map result is a list of (key is word and the value is one). In you example it will be the key house and the value is the currentconsumption for that house.

In the reducer, in the word example, the output of the mapper will be the input for the reducer. The reducer sums for the same words the 1s to get the overall sum of that word. the results will be a list(the key is the word  and the value is the sum). Same thing with your case and as a result you will get as a key the house and the value will be the currentConsumption.

Comment: Hi thanks for your insigh, i am not sure how to implement this using the hadoop. I am aware only using the appengine mapreducer. I am a beginner following only this example http://ikaisays.com/page/2/
Any help greatly appreciated. I am ready to share my email if needed so that we can hangout.

Comment: I have tried to go through the link. However, I did not find the example you are talking about. I recommend you to start with the simplest example word count. Try to get the code ready, executed, then modify on the top of it whatever you want. I think the word count example will be helpful in this case as you want to do the sum. It is really different from Hadoop, just tried to read...

Comment: Hi Dhoha thanks for looking into the link. I had followed the exmaple for the word count given my IKAI and it worked like a charm. But the problem is there is no reducer used. I am struggling to use reducer.Also i had experimented all the sample programs in this one http://ikaisays.com/2010/07/09/using-the-java-mapper-framework-for-app-engine/

Comment: Can i have your email id so that i can send you the codes.

Comment: Yes, this is why I told you that it is very different from the Hadoop. I suggest now to imitate the word count program in order to write your own program. Sorry, I did not work on this platform. I'm not sure if I can really help you. Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Sum requires a reducer step since it is an aggregation operator.

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/demo/main.py#256 for a Python example that uses a reduce phase and https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/java/example/src/com/google/appengine/demos/mapreduce/entitycount/ for a Java example.

Comment: Please include relevant code samples into the answer. That way the answer is self contained and not susceptible to things changing in the trunk of a repository.